# Deedle: errors using Frame.mapColValues

Tags: f#, deedle

I'm following a tutorial:
http://dkowalski.com/blog/archive/2014/01/11/f-deedle-and-computational-investing.aspx
 and when I try to apply normalization to all the columns of "stocks" Frame, using `Frame.mapColValues`, I obtain the following error message:
``` System.InvalidOperationException: OptionalValue.Value: Value is not available
   in Deedle.OptionalValue``1.get_Value() in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Common\Common.fs:riga 35
   in FSI_0046.normalized@52-8.Invoke(ObjectSeries``1 os) in C:\Users\Bruno-Astarita\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestDeedle02\TestDeedle02\TestTutorial01.fsx:riga 52
   in <StartupCode$Deedle>.$Series.f@257-13[K,V,R](Func``3 f, Int32 i, K key, V v) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:riga 358
   in <StartupCode$Deedle>.$Series.newVector@354-1.Invoke(Int32 i, Tuple``2 tupledArg) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:riga 355
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.mapi@129.DoMoveNext(b& )
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator``1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T](IEnumerable``1 source)
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ArrayModule.OfSeq[T](IEnumerable``1 source)
   in Deedle.Series``2.Select[R](Func``3 f) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:riga 352
   in Deedle.Series``2.Select[R](Func``2 f) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:riga 365
   in Deedle.SeriesModule.MapValues[T,R,K](FSharpFunc``2 f, Series``2 series) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\SeriesModule.fs:riga 451
   in <StartupCode$FSI_0046>.$FSI_0046.main@() in C:\Users\Bruno-Astarita\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestDeedle02\TestDeedle02\TestTutorial01.fsx:riga 49
Stopped due to error ```
I tried to find the problem making a step-by-step procedure based on source code in `FrameModule.fs`, and the error raises at the instruction `Series.mapValues f`.
Where I'm wrong?
Many thanks.

**Update**
After many tests, the problem seems be arised by the row `let firstItem = osAsFloat.GetAt(0)` from the tutorial. If I try to substitute it with `let firstItem = 2.0` everything is ok. Still is not clear for me this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason of problem. In some Series in the Frame, there are missing values in correspondence to the first element. If I do not use those Series, everything is ok.